# What does the matrix $AA^T$ represent when $A$ is the incidence matrix of a graph?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory

We know that, if we represent graph as matrix with its cells containing presence of edge, then $A^2$ will represent $2$ length walks between $i$ & $j.$

In general, what would matrix $AA^T$ mean?

Comment: I assume you're talking about directed graphs here, since for undirected graphs the adjacency matrix is symmetric. At any rate, depending on which role you give rows and columns, the answer is that $AA^T$ tells you about nodes that have either a common parent or a common child, while $A^TA$ is the other.

Comment: The title of the question asks about the incidence matrix while the content of the question seems to concern the adjacency matrix. The incidence matrix times its transpose is the [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of the graph.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the incidence matrix is not the same as the adjacency matrix.

The adjacency matrix $A$ is defined such that $A_{ij} = 1$ iff node $i$ is connected to node $j$ and is zero otherwise.

On the other hand, the incidence matrix of an undirected$^*$ graph is defined such that$$
E_{ij} = \begin{cases}
+1 &\text{if edge $i$ is incident on node $j$}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
Here "incident" means the edge connects to the node, i.e., touches it.

Under this definition, you can easily see that $E'E = A + D$ where "$A$" is the adjacency matrix and "$D$" is a diagonal matrix such that $D_{ii}$ is equal to the degree of node $i$.

---

$^*$For a directed graph, the incidence matrix is a little more complicated, having both +1, -1, and 0 valued entries depending on whether a edge enters or exits a node.